# Bash PS1 shows $ instead of # for root

Tags: linux, bash, root, ps1

When logging into root, the default prompt when echoed is `\s-\v\$`, which shows as `bash-4.2#`. I am trying to play around with the bash prompt so it displays the working directory.
`export PS1="\w \$"`.

The prompt displays correctly, however, the symbol `\$` does not transform into a `#`, even though my `$UID` is 0, which kind of defeats the purpose of omitting the user symbol `\u`. Is there something extra I have to add, or does that symbol not work if I export it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
export PS1="\w \$"
```

This doesn't set `$PS1` to `\w \$`, it sets it to `\w $`, as you can see if you type:

```
echo "$PS1"
```

Use single quotes:

```
export PS1='\w \$'
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe the solution was so simple! How come "\w" parsed correctly, though? Almost every single symbol (\u, \h, even the color prompts [\033...) worked correctly for me inside of the PS1 prompt.

Comment: @bark: Probably because `$` is a special character within double quotes, so `"\$"` escapes the `$` so it's a literal `$` character. I'm not sure about all the details, but that seems like a plausible explanation.

Comment: In scripts, the `'` quote does not get parsed/expanded: its value is dumped straight into the variable. The `"` quote DOES get parsed/expanded, so spaces get expanded to `\ `, `\n` gets expanded to a newline, etc. Since `\w` does not have a "special" meaning, the `\` was actually expanded to `\\` to make `\\w`, which was assigned to the variable as a literal `\w`. The `\$` <i>does</i> have a "special" meaning, so it became a literal `$`.

Comment: @OnlineCop: `\n` *isn't* expanded to a newline in bash double-quoted strings. You can use `$'...'` to get something resembling C expansion rules. (BTW, I think the mix of backticks and backslahes messed up some of the content in your comment.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: `echo -e "Hello\nworld"` ;)

Comment: @OnlineCop: That's expanded by `echo -e`, not by the shell. (Well, `echo` is a shell builtin, but `/bin/echo` does the same thing.) And the `\n` sequence is also recognized in `$PS1`.

Comment: this is better (double escape): export PS1="\w \\$"

Comment: @MichaelA. It's equivalent, and if you prefer it that's fine, but I don't see how it's better.

Answer (score 2):

the slash will be gone in the "". Just need to add one more to keep it.
Either

```
export PS1='\w \$'
```

or

```
export PS1="\w \\$"
```

works for you.

You can combine '' and "". For example:

```
export PS1="\w blabla"'\$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
export PS1="\w \\$"
```

I don't know why it works. But it works.I have originally seen this here: [cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html#comment-173739)